# Use jsf as template engine on EAR

Tags: java, jsf, template-engine, ear

Thinking about html e-mails for our e-commerce site I thought about reusing jsf and other 3rd party libraries as a template engine to create the e-mails on our application server *(Glassfish 3, EAR)*.

Is it possible to manually run jsf with a local file and initialize the necessary bean to capture the html output to be saved in a String?

*Why have a look at other template frameworks if jsf provides much flexibility and could do the job.*

Comment: JSF is way, _way_ more than just templating. It's not even all that good at just generating HTML, if that's what you want. What _do_ you want?

Comment: Create html which will look similar to the website to be used within an e-mail. Jsf was just an idea to be used instead of a template framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using JSF on glassfish for generating emails inside of a EJB. I based my work on the following blog post:

- https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-create-email-from-jsf-templates

Basically it works when the JSF is rendered in a request that was made from the web.

I currently try to also use JSF in unit tests and scheduled executions but I currently have trouble to start JSF.

The following class is doing the initialization of Faces:

com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer

Unfortunately it requires a complete implementation of the Servlet 3.0 implementation. In my cases starting the servlet engine also requires an JMX server.

From my current experience I would recommend to use a template engine with less dependencies e.g.

- Velocity http://velocity.apache.org/
- Freemarker http://freemarker.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the updated link. Our mails are send in an EAR so not in the current faces request and would require to mock JSF which then would seam too much. We use freemarker` library the last years and its working great and i think easier to setup.